# RTC - Is it possible to have personal repo for each-user like Git provides

Tags: git, rtc

I am new too **RTC** version control tool, before this I was using **git** as my version control tool. In **git** each user used to have one separate user(personal) repository, first we will commit all my local changes there and do all this **jenkins** build and review and other ceremonies. When everything successfully done we will go-ahead and merge our personal repo to our master. What is the advantage here is, my master build never used to fail.

But in **RTC**, we never find anything like that. Straight-away we will **commit** all our changes to master and mostly the builds are failing.

Is there any facility to do the above git setup in **RTC**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Straight-away we will commit all our changes to master

No, you commit to your personal repository workspace, and then, after controlling the quality of what is committed (through for instance a [Jenkins build definition](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.build.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_hudson_build_def.html) triggered on your own desktop, in a [dedicated build workspace](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?re=1&topic=/com.ibm.team.build.doc/topics/tcreateworkspace.html&scope=null)), you push (deliver) to the stream referenced by the repo workspace.

See "[Repository workspaces in team environments](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.scm.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_scm_eclipse_teamuser_new_ws.html)":

> As a team member, your **repository workspaces are private development areas where you can work on your own or combine your work with contributions from your team**.
>   Your work remains private to the workspace until you decide to deliver it to a team flow target such as a shared stream.